# Will DataProc Presto pick up new nodes automatically?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, autoscaling, presto, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a DataProc cluster with 10 nodes and Presto installed. The Autoscaling function of cluster is on. I wonder when Presto is running and the cluster scales up, will Presto be able to pick up and use the additional nodes automatically? I didn't find an answer from Google's doc.

My concern is that is I need to manually restart Presto, it defeats the purpose of autoscaling. My hope is that the cluster and autoscale when presto gets a larger job.

Comment: Presto can add nodes at runtime (in some cases to existing queries), so I would expect this to work.  I'd just try it out and see what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presto will automatically pick up new nodes as the cluster scales.

However, be aware that Dataproc autoscaling currently only supports scaling based on YARN metrics (see the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/autoscaling#how_autoscaling_works)). Your cluster won't autoscale based on Presto query load, but rather the load on YARN.