# Dataproc: How to implement auto scale based on presto load

Tags: google-cloud-platform, presto, autoscaling, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-dataproc-serverless

I am applying presto optionally to Dataproc.
I want to autoscale based on the load of the presto query, but when I set autoscaling-policies and increase the query load, it does not autoscale

I read the following article
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56067581/will-dataproc-presto-pick-up-new-nodes-automatically](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
It says that dataproc will autoscale based on YARN index. However, I believe that presto cannot autoscale because it does not consume YARN memory, is that correct?
how can I make it autoscaleable?